# Introducing Swift in OC Project Causes Compilation Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

The project is OC, is a xcworkspace contains a number of sub-xcodeproj, I modify the code in the sub-xcodeproj, I created a Swift object in the sub-xcodeproj, and press the Xcode prompts to add the Bridging-Header file, compiled the following error. How do I solve this compilation error?

```html
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal_$_Business)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore_$_Business)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch_$_Business)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation_$_Business)
  "__swift_slowAlloc", referenced from:
      _swift_rt_swift_slowAlloc in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics_$_Business)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation_$_Business)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin_$_Business)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit_$_Business)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage_$_Business)
  "__swift_slowDealloc", referenced from:
      _swift_rt_swift_slowDealloc in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC_$_Business in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC_$_Business)
  "value witness table for Builtin.UnknownObject", referenced from:
      full type metadata for Business.TestSwift in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
  "__swift_getInitializedObjCClass", referenced from:
      _swift_rt_swift_getInitializedObjCClass in libBusiness.a(TestSwift.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: did you proceed?

Comment: Have you added Bridging-Header file?

Comment: Ever figure that out?